# Where is the documentation that explains chaining a field name after findOne() in Mongo?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

MongoDB's [documentation for `find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) talks about chaining `limit()` and `sort()` to a query. The [documentation for `findOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) makes no mention of chaining these methods or anything else for that matter.

In the collection `widgets`, if we run `db.widgets.findOne({}, {name:1})`, we get this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("58bfaba203063eab31a1923e"),
  "name": "Deluxe spinning widget"
}
```

But if we chain `name` to the prior command, as in `db.widgets.findOne({}, {name:1}).name`, we get just the value of `name`, like this:

```
 Deluxe spinning widget
```

Is there any documentation behind this?

If not, would it be correct to say that this example is not chaining at all but simple [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to retrieve the value of a key in an object?

Comment: Downvoter, please explain why the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any documentation behind this?

This is standard behaviour of javascript. As such, it is not explicitly described in mongodb documentation, there's no need.

> If not, would it be correct to say that this example is not chaining at all but simple dot notation to retrieve the value of a key in an object?

Correct.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It's what I suspected but appreciate the confirmation.

Comment: @samurai_jane: don't forget to accept helpful answers.